# My CTE query is not working as I expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

Here is my query:

```
WITH Ase AS 
(
    SELECT CAST(AVG(percent_water AS w) AS DECIMAL(10,2))
    FROM dbo.countries
)
SELECT un_continential_region, un_subregion, Ase
FROM dbo.countries
WHERE percent_water > 0
GROUP BY un_continential_region, un_subregion
ORDER BY Ase DESC;
```

The error I am getting is

> AVG is not a recognized built-in function name

The goal for this query is I want to cast the Average percent water as a decimal, then group it by un_continential_region, and Un_subregion.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: 1. Please use a meaningful title... your title as it stands tells us nothing about the goal of your query. 2. Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results, otherwise how are we supposed to know what your query it attempting to do?

Comment: 3. Please read the documentation for a cte... when using a cte, you select from the CTE name, its your new table i.e. `select from ase`, its not a new column. And you will need to alias you new columns created with AG once you get the other syntax correct.

Comment: I think the error is because of the `as w` inside the cast operation fwiw. Not sure of the intent.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a CTE, just perform the wanted calculation in the select clause:

```
SELECT
      un_continential_region
    , un_subregion
    , CAST(AVG(percent_water) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Ase
FROM dbo.countries
WHERE percent_water > 0
GROUP BY
      un_continential_region
    , un_subregion
ORDER BY
      Ase DESC;
```

Also note `AVG(percent_water AS w)` isn't valid the "as w" does not belong inside those parentheses. Also, it may be that you wanted to force the data into a decimal before averaging, in that case then use:

```
    , AVG(CAST(percent_water AS DECIMAL(10,2))) AS Ase
```

Comment: probably you want to do `WHERE cast(percent_water as decimal(10,2)) > 0` but who knows =)

Comment: Or maybe OP wants the average across the whole thing, in which case you want `SUM(SUM(percent_water)) OVER () / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()`